# Rails 3: cropping the display of an image on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, jcrop

I was wondering if anyone has ever made something that would let a user change the cropping of an image's display on the fly?

What I'm imagining is a user uploads a photo which does not get cropped and when the photo is displayed on their dashboard they can select a 'crop display' option and select a rectangular area of the image to be displayed, however, the actual photo is not cropped, and a user could repeat this and display a different section of the same photo. Anyone ever done this or have idea on how it could be done? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Not an exact answer, but you would need to store the image data, The starting x & y, as well as the ending x & y. Then you can use css to position the image based off those saved values. In terms of creating the interface to do it, There's a variety of options. I suggest looking into making a resize able transparent div with a border. http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/ Maybe use something like that, and create the div at the x&y of where the user first clicks. Just make the div transparent as supposed to with the colours in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly/) does this.

It's a Rack framework with on-the-fly image processing as one of its main points.  Basic usage:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  image_accessor :cover_image
end

<%= image_tag @album.cover_image.url %>
<%= image_tag @album.cover_image.thumb('400x200#').url %>
<%= image_tag @album.cover_image.jpg.url %>
<%= image_tag @album.cover_image.process(:greyscale).encode(:tiff).url %>
```

To make your example work, you could surely use any cropping tool and pass the arguments to the server to create multiple re-usable "crops", or other views (note the grayscale, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this jquery plugin as an interface http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/ and you should watch this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images to get know how it works "under the hood" :)